# How do I vertically center two elements side by side, and then have their inner margins equidistant from the vertical center line?

Tags: css, css-position

So, as per below, I have two elements: my name and an unordered list.

I want both elements to be centered vertically and side to side in a browser window (no matter the size of the window.)

I also want both elements centered horizontally sort of, so that the right side of the left element and the left side of the right element lie on the vertical center line.

I hope that's clear! Basically I want these two bits to be side to side and centered vertically and horizontally on the page.

I've sort of got what I want by floating both elements to the left, and then adjusting the margins for each element. But perhaps there is a better and more precise way?

```
<body>
    <h1>
        My Name
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <li>
            about
        </li>
        <li>
            resume
        </li>
        <li>
            samples
        </li>
        <li>
            blog
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please show the way you have tried (jsfiddle, jsbin, etc.).

Comment: can you add the css code

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use `inline-block` for header and both list and list elements, alihn it vertically and use `:before` pseudoelement for body (or any other wrapper) to set it in the middle:

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dAiCw)

**html**

```
<h1>My Name</h1>
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
body:before,
h1,
ul, li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```